# What software can we use to create this slideshow video

Tags: video, video-editor

I am trying to create this video using adobe premier pro.

In each slide, I will have 3 different images slides in with different effect and timing.

However, it is a bit complex for me and I found difficult to change photos in slide, as I need to cater the motion effect, size, of other two images in the timeline.

I had tried window movie maker, it is very simple but it seems that it only allows transition of one whole image. I can't freely adjust the 3 different images to slide in with different angle, speed, stay on time, and fading effect, and stay on one screen.

May I know is there any other software that can produce the similar effect as in the video?

Comment: To me it looks like something that would be done in Powerpoint.

Comment: I agree. You just need to use an image editor to cut the overall image on screen into smaller images of each dish. From there you can set custom animation to each image as required. This could be done in powerpoint, keynote or even google docs!

Comment: Yes. However I need to save this in video format so we can play it on LED TV.

Answer (score 3):

You should give a chance to Sony Vegas 8 or newer. In Sony Vegas you can place as many images as you wish and make it "fly in" or "fly out" over a background which can be a solid color, gradient (both self-generated) and/or a background image.

The process itself is quite easy. You set the background in the timeline for the duration that you need. Then simply add as many tracks as you need for each image that you wish to get animated over the background, place the item in the timeline, enter the "Pan and Crop" function of the timeline and create the movement that you wish.

See this video for a comprehensive explanation about the **Pan and Crop** function in Sony Vegas.

In Sony Vegas you can create per-track and/or per-event motion by using the proper tools.

If you are using Linux you may find KDEnlive as a good alternative for Sony Vegas.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe After Effects, you can import each picture as a layer and animate them separately. Check out tutorials on youtube, there are plenty out there : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nt-BMN_GIw

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the easiest software then Powerpoint or Keynote seem to be the best options. Keynote can export presentations as a .mov file via it's share menu, as shown in the following video tutorial:

- [Exporting Keynote presentations to video for sharing on websites](http://www.techwithintent.com/2011/12/exporting-keynote-presentations-to-video-for-sharing-on-websites/)

Powerpoint 2010 allows you to share as a video too, as described in the following help article:

- [Turn your presentation into a video](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/powerpoint-help/turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-HA010336763.aspx#_Toc252973122)

If you already use Premier to edit videos I think purchasing another high-profile app to just animate slide-ins would be a rather unnecessary investment, plus an office suite always comes in handy!